# Is there a masked input field type for Craft?

Tags: fieldtypes

Is there anything like the [EE add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ndg-masked-input) for Craft?

This would be *really* useful for part numbers, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is but I would love to see something like this. First party would be even cooler....

Comment: Probably not something we would add to the core. You should ask the developer and see if they can port it to Craft ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote one! [MN Match Input](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mn_matchinput). You specify an `Input Mask` and the entry won't save if `preg_match($inputMask, $value)` isn't 1. So you get all the power of [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (lots of rope...)